# Ignore "NA" as missing value (Python)?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with GEO column:

```
GEO
-------
EMEA
NA
LA
ASAP
EMEA
NA
NA
```

But when I read it in python:

```
df.read_excel(path + '\\' + file)
```

It reads "NA" as missing:

```
GEO
-------
EMEA

LA
ASAP
EMEA
```

I know how to tell python to consider something else as missing value, but I haven't found how to tell to ignore "NA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `na_values` and `keep_default_na` according to the documentation of [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
# This list was built from the default na_values, minus NA
NA_VALUES = ['', '#N/A', '#N/A N/A', '#NA', '-1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '-NaN', '-nan',
             '1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '<NA>', 'N/A', 'NULL', 'NaN', 'n/a', 'nan', 'null']

df = pd.read_excelpath + '\\' + file, na_values=NA_VALUES, keep_default_na=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    GEO
0  EMEA
1    NA
2    LA
3  ASAP
4  EMEA
5    NA
6    NA
```